# WCF returns object with only default values

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a test class `CustObject` which has `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes. When I return this to the client, however, all values are the default value.

Service Side:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustObject
{
    [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]
    public int n1;
    [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]
    public int n2;

    [DataMember]
    public int val1 = 552;

    [DataMember]
    public int? val2 = 88;

    [DataMember]
    int val3 = 11;

    [DataMember]
    string val4 = "hello world";


    public CustObject()
    {
        n1 = 1;
        n2 = 2;
    }

    private int nprivate = 18;



}



    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
{

    public CustObject Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        CustObject test =  new CustObject();
        Console.WriteLine("Should read that n1 = {0} and n2 = {1}", test.n1, test.n2);
        return test;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    CustObject Foo();
}
```

Client side:

```
    public static void Main ()
    {
        CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient(
                                      new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None),
                                       new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/CalculatorService"));



        CustObject custObj = client.Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(custObj.val1 + ", " + custObj.val2 + ", " + custObj.val1 + ", " + custObj.val2 + ", " +
                          custObj.val3 + ", " + custObj.val4);

        //Step 3: Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources.
        client.Close ();


        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Press <ENTER> to terminate client.");
        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

And the output is just `0, 0, 0, 0, 0,` (the last value is an empty string)

I have read a ton of stuff to try to figure out this problem. It seems that even though the values are initialized, the xml conversion is just giving every field a default value. I can't figure out why.

I used svutil to create the proxy file.

Comment: And is it working correctly if you try to send an object with custom not the default values?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Look at the CustObject class above --- those values are set yet the the returned data is all default.

Comment: Yes i see that but have you tried to send an object with custom values i think it would be important to know if the custom values wouldn't be serialized too.

Comment: `public int val1 = 552;` is a custom value. Therefore, I don't know what you mean. This object has custom values.

Comment: I mean when you create your object after that you set some properties and not use the ones you wrote in your object declaration.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I have                                                 public CustObject()
    {
        n1 = 1;
        n2 = 2;
    }`

Comment: Ok i recreated your Test Project and for me it is working, i used a generated service reference and CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient(); i created like this the client.

Comment: Is there anything different about how you did it?

Comment: No i created first a WCf service where i put your code in, then a console application with a service reference and it worked with the little change i wrote.

Comment: What was the change you made? It didn't work before the change?

Comment: The change was in the construction of the client, and that i changed because i just wanted to quick try your code and don't create an endpoint. I think your problem is somewhere in the config files if you could edit your question and add your config files too i think we could figure it out whats the problem.

Comment: I'm not using config files. I set it up all in code.

Answer (score 5):

One of the issues with using a generated proxies, whether is is through svutil or adding a service reference, is updating your service.  Any time I find I am not getting the expected values in a field, it is because I changed something in my service and didn't re-generate my proxy code.  If you renamed a property (even changing case), or change a data type, rather than throwing an exception, you just get the default value for that data type.  Try running svutil again.

Note: This is one of the reasons I stopped using generated proxies and now use a ChannelFactory to conenct to WCF.

Comment: Well this is all just simple testing. I have run svutil and recompiled many many times, just to make sure its not something I'm doing. It is good advice, though.

Answer (score 0):

After an entire day, I found the solution. This may apply to all those using Mono! Very useful solution.

I am using Mono and the svutil for Mono (at least on ubuntu) generates output code that is correct except one particularly important point.

The proxy class for the custom class must be contained within the same namespace as the actual custom class defined in the service!

For the example above, in the output.cs file generated by svutil, I had to surround the proxy CustObject with the Service namespace.

I figured this out by running the .NET version of svutil in Windows and comparing the generated code files. I would say this is probably a bug in Mono's svutil.

Comment: Good to know.  Just an FYI, using a ChannelFactory instead of a generated proxy should prevent this from being an issue.

Comment: Its strange that it won't throw exceptions or perhaps get caught by the compiler.

Comment: The reason is does this is to protect your application against changes to a 3rd party WCF service.  I'd hate to have a production application break because of a change to a service that may or may not be significant.  The issue with exceptions or compiler warnings is that Visual Studio does not know the difference between a service in the current solution or an external service.